# Is the Scot referendum the biggest one of its type in modern history? And other questions

Tags: britain, independence, scotland

Also I know a lot of regions that are fighting/claiming independence. What convinced the union to come to this decision. What are the Scots woes that drove them to ask for it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "of its type"? i.e., whether you mean any referendum on independence? Or specifically a binding, independence referendum? And/or one **authorised by the central government** (which I think is the more notable characteristic here)? Also, the "other questions" bits should be redirected to [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com/). They are political in nature and they just make this question too broad + matter of opinion.

Comment: "And other questions" doesn't work well here, just ask one single clear and definite question.

Comment: The 1995 Quebec referendum, at 4.7MM votes cast, is more than 1.1MM votes larger than the 2014 Scottish referendum at only 3.6MM votes cast:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_referendum,_1995 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_independence_referendum,_2014

Comment: The 1980 Quebec Referendum, at 3.7MM votes cast, was about 100,000 votes larger: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_referendum,_1980

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Others

South Sudan passed a similar referendum in 2008. South Sudan has a population of 8 million +, compared to Scotland's population of 5 million +.

Algeria passed a similar referendum in 1962. The current population is about 38 million, I don't have the numbers for the 1962.

Here is a list of independence referendums starting in 1848 with the former US colony Liberia, up to Scotland:

http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Independence_referendum
*(use the occasion to adopt wikiwand! :)*

### Scotland

A portion of the Scottish population wanted independence (about 45%). I'm currently studying in Scotland and I would say the reasons are:

1) Nationalism / Patriotism

2) Feeling of being neglected by London

The election was really split along income level lines with the "poorer" wanting independence (nothing to loose), and the "richer" fearing their economy would only get worse if cut off from London. Poverty reaches third world levels in some areas of Glasgow and Dundee (the two biggest YES cities).